# Why is this instance variable 5 instead of 4?

Tags: ruby

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(value)
    @value
  end
end

class Testo
  attr_accessor :root

  def method
    @root = Node.new(4)
    current = @root
    current.value = 5
  end
end

testing = Testo.new
testing.method
puts testing.root.value #=> Returns 5
```

I don't understand. Is the local variable `current` now an instance variable? Is it a copy of `@root`? Shouldn't `root` be 4 instead of 5?

Comment: `@root` and `current` now both _reference_ the same `Node` object. So if you modify the object that `current` is referencing you are modifying the exact same object that `@root` references.

Comment: @JKillian At the risk of sounding pedantic, it might be less confusing to say that both variables refer to the *same instance of `Node`*.

Comment: @coreyward Why would "instance of Node" be any less or more confusing than "Node object"? Those two terms are completely synonymous.

Comment: Well, there is also a `Node` object, which is an instance of `Class`.

Comment: @sepp2k Two reasons: 1) the ruby community largely uses “instance of” terminology, and 2) as @Jörg W Mittag pointed out, `Node` itself is an object, which neither `@root` or `current` reference.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Ruby are references to objects.

What you are really doing is instantiating a new Node object with `value=4` and then referencing to it with 'current' variable(name) (also `@root` is referencing the same object) and then changing its value to 5.

Comment: Wow that is actually very helpful. I'm not sure why I missed that. Would you mind explaining to me why something like this doesn't work the same way?

`one = "one"

=> "one"

irb(main):002:0> two = one

=> "one"

irb(main):003:0> two

=> "one"

irb(main):004:0> two = "two"

=> "two"

irb(main):005:0> one

=> "one"`

Comment: You are creating an object (string) with value "one" and referencing it with the variables one and two. When writing 'two="two"' a new object (string) with value "two" is created an the variable two is now referencing it. Variable one still points to "one".